# Fail entire SSIS Package in case of Exception

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have a SSIS package with lots of containers and logic. I am running an additional task (which I want to run independently) let's say it acts as an *Event Listener*. When this separate task is errored, I want to error out the entire package. I thought, it should work by default but to my surprise, it's not:-

[image]

I have tried setting both `FailPackageOnFailure` & `FailParentOnFailure` properties on both the parent container & the child container but it's not working.

Comment: Make a variable. When the listener hits an error, set that variable to something and have your main processes check that variable before each run. When the variable changes and it gets checked, tell the process to fail.

Comment: @dfundako - Thanks, but how I'll tell the process to fail?

Comment: How should I know? Its your code.

Comment: I want to error out the package & stop package execution. @dfundako

Comment: if you want fail separate task when sequence container 2 failed, then put sequence container 2 first, if you want to make they run together to have good performance, then you should clear know which step in Sequence Container 3 that can run when Sequence Container 2 finished

Answer (score 3):

I was about to ask exactly the content of your last comment.

Failure of one piece of a package won't make another, unconnected piece stop executing. Once the executing piece is done, the package *will* fail, but `Sequence Container 3` has no way to know what's happening in `Sequence Container 2`.

Which, honestly, is what we want. If `Sequence Container 3` is doing DML, you could leave your data in an unfortunate state if an unrelated failure elsewhere in the package suddenly made everything come to a screeching halt.

If you don't want `Sequence Container 3` to run if `Sequence Container 2` fails, then just run a precedence constraint from `Sequence Container 2` to `Sequence Container 3`, #3 won't execute until #2 succeeds **and** the `Execute SQL Task` succeeds.

Comment: I agree that we don't want to leave the sql operation in between but in this case I am running some complex sql logic which gets stuck sometimes and I want to kill it using _flag_ from Sequence container 2.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with Eric's answer. Let me explain to you why raising a flag on error won't work. 
I redesign the package so it includes the flag check. 
[image]
[image]
Let's say we have a success flag as user variable which is by default False.

Now we set this variable as True at the end of sequence 2 execution marking the success of all the other tasks in that sequence.
[image]

The second part is put into a for loop which runs only once(if at all). It checks if the success variable is true and only then run the inner tasks. It looks like below:

[image]
The problem is, the success variable check at the start of the for loop will always have the inital value which is false(because it runs in parallel with seq 2 and doesn't wait till seq 2 ends). Hence the second part is never executed. Now change the initial value of success variable to true and run the package again. Play by disabling the error prone tasks and run the package. You will understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I came up with a similar issue.
The container will never fail by itself, it's a dummy object.

The property FailParentOnFailure in the **components** of the container need to be set
to TRUE
(or FailPackageOnFailure or both).

In your screenshot, the properties in the **Execute SQL** component need to be set to TRUE.